# 'QMessageBox::critical' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: qt, arguments, overloading, qmessagebox

I want to display an error message whenever my independent thread encounters the word "alert1" in a specific .txt file. But I get the above error inside the monitorForAlerts() inside mythread.cpp file. The line expectedly executes if I were to place it inside dialog.cpp. So I guess this is due to non-inheritance of this object. Can you please advise me how to solve this error for the given code?

Here is the code:
dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>
#include "mythread.h"
namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

public slots:

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

mythread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTimer>
#define ALERTS_MESSAGE_STORAGE_PATH "E:\\QT1\\simpleGUIThread2\\simpleGUIThread2\\usbAlert.txt"
#define TIMER_VALUE                      500
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();
    QString name;
    void monitorForAlerts();
    int exec();

public slots:

signals:
    void testSignal(QString message);

public slots:

};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->show();
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ui->label->hide();
}
```

mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include "dialog.h"
MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    exec();
}

int MyThread::exec()
{
    while(1)
    {
        monitorForAlerts();
        emit(testSignal("hello world!!"));
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void MyThread::monitorForAlerts()
{
    QString response = ALERTS_MESSAGE_STORAGE_PATH;
    QFile resp(response);
    resp.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    resp.close();
    QFile resp1(response);
    char buf[121];
    char buf1[] = "alert1";
    char buf2[] = "alert2";

    resp1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    while(resp1.size() == 0)
    {
        Sleep(3000);
    }
    qint64 lineLength = resp1.readLine(buf, sizeof(buf));
    resp1.close();
    if(strcmp(buf,buf1) == 0)
    {
        QFile::remove(ALERTS_MESSAGE_STORAGE_PATH);
        qDebug()<<"warning 1!!";
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("ERROR"),tr("Large change in illumination.\nPlease re-capture reference image.\n"));
    }
    if(strcmp(buf,buf2) == 0)
    {
        QFile::remove(ALERTS_MESSAGE_STORAGE_PATH);
        qDebug()<<"warning 2!!";
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("ERROR"),tr("The camera position has been moved or an object is obscuring its view.\nPlease check the device.\n"));
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "mythread.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyThread mThread1;
    mThread1.name = "mThread1";
    mThread1.start();

    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

LATEST UPDATE*********************************************************************************************************************

Hi Zlatomir,
I choose to take your 1st advice. I have created a signal that the thread will emit and connect it to a slot for QDialog. Please let me know if my understanding is correct, because I do not know where to implement the connect(), since the signal is declared in mythread.h and the slot in dialog.h. The connection type argument for connect is Qt::QueuedConnection, so that gui elements from another thread different than main-thread.
are NOT created. Is this statement correct? and where do I place this?

```
connect( mThread, SIGNAL(alertSignal(QString)), this, SLOT(alertSlot(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

mythread.h

```
//....
signals:
void alertSignal(QString message);
//....
```

dialog.h

```
//....
public slots:
void alertSlot(QString message);
//....
```

mythread.cpp

```
//....
    if(strcmp(buf,buf1) == 0)
    {
        QFile::remove(ALERTS_MESSAGE_STORAGE_PATH);
        qDebug()<<"warning 1!!";
        emit(alertSignal("alert1"));
    }
    else if(strcmp(buf,buf2) == 0)
    {
        QFile::remove(ALERTS_MESSAGE_STORAGE_PATH);
        qDebug()<<"warning 2!!";
        emit(alertSignal("alert2"));
    }
```

dialog.cpp

```
void Dialog::alertSlot(QString message)
{
    if(strcmp(message, "alert1"))
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("ERROR"),tr("Large change in illumination.\nPlease re-capture reference image.\n"));
    else if(strcmp(message, "alert2"))
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("ERROR"),tr("The camera position has been moved or an object is obscuring its view.\nPlease check the device.\n"));
}
```

Now if this were correct, how do i implement the connect() and in which file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument is the problem, in your case `this` is not a good argument, because there `this` is a pointer to a `MyThread` instance, and `MyThread` is not a QWidget (is not derived from QWidget).

To solve this you can show the `QMessageBox::critical` from a slot in mainwindow (the `Dialog` class in your code, there you pass the instance of main-window that is a QWidget) and connect that slot with a signal that you emit from your thread, make sure that the [connection type](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) argument for [connect](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-3) is `Qt::QueuedConnection`, so that you don't try to create gui elements from another thread different than main-thread.

Another option would be to validate the data before you start the second thread and to tell
the user that he needs to provide the right files.

LE: Also check the [QThread](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#details)'s documentation for the recommended way to use the class, now it's recommended not to derive from QThread.

LE2 - answer to the update
That connect can be made where ever you can have the two instances that you want to connect, in your case `main.cpp` is a good place to connect those (don't forget to fully qualify the name for connect: `QObject::connect`):

```
//...
    MyThread mThread1;
    mThread1.name = "mThread1";
    mThread1.start();

    Dialog w;
    QObject::connect( &mThread1, SIGNAL(alertSignal(QString)), &w, SLOT(alertSlot(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    w.show();
//...
```